# Different modes for each axis in scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter

Tags: python, scipy

Is it possible to use a different border mode (i.e. `wrap` for the first axis and `reflect` for the second one) while using `scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter`?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes - if your scipy is new enough. Simply pass a list of modes, one for each axis.

Quoting the help text ([scipy version 0.19.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter)):

> The mode parameter determines how the array borders are handled. Valid modes are {‘reflect’, ‘constant’, ‘nearest’, ‘mirror’, ‘wrap’}. cval is the value used when mode is equal to ‘constant’. **A list of modes with length equal to the number of axes can be provided to specify different modes for different axes.** Default is ‘reflect’

Note thas this changed with version 0.19. In 0.18 and before there was no option to pass multiple modes.

Comment: As I am under the 0.15.1 version, I cannot pass a list of modes. But I will write my custom method using the original model: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L251